# Can't upload photos to S3 with Fog in Rails : Connection reset by peer (Errno::ECONNRESET)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

When I try to upload a local file to S3 like this in the rails console `photo.file = File.open(photo.tempfile.file.file)`, I got this error :

```
Excon::Errors::SocketError: Connection reset by peer (Errno::ECONNRESET)
from /home/pubudu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/openssl/buffering.rb:383:in `syswrite_nonblock'
```

What might be the issue? The aws credentials are set correctly, the region is set correctly. I use carrierwave and fog to upload the files. The file im uploading is in the Rails root directory.

Comment: What is the value of photo.tempfile.file.file?

Comment: @eabraham It's the full path to the file

Comment: Can you post one of the image paths?

Comment: @eabraham Thanks for the help! I found the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Just found the problem. I was using `Rails.root` for the uploader's directory. For S3 this won't work. Remove that part and everything works fine!